# I would like to have a module have its own db connection different form the main app in Yii

Tags: php, yii, module

my model inside **booksImported** module

**../protected/modules/booksImported/models/Importedbooks.php**

```
class Importedbooks extends CActiveRecord
{
 public function getDbConnection()
 {
    return Yii::app()->myModuleDb;
 }
}
```

my **booksImported** module

**../protected/modules/booksImported/BooksImportedModule.php**

```
class BooksImportedModule extends CWebModule
{

public function init()
{
    // this method is called when the module is being created
    // you may place code here to customize the module or the application

    // import the module-level models and components
    $this->setImport(array(
        'booksImported.models.*',
        'booksImported.components.*',
    ));
}

public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
{
    if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
    {
        // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
        // you may place customized code here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

my main.php, i created a new component called it **myModuleDb**, i managed to create the model using this component

```
    // database settings are configured in database.php
     'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

     'myModuleDb'=>array(
            'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbimports',
            'username' => 'my_username',
            'password' => 'my_password',
            'class'=>'CDbConnection'
            ),
```

When i try to access my module control  **localhost/testYii/booksImported/booksImported/index** , i get **CException, Property "BooksImportedModule.db" is not define**d.

Comment: Follow the guide here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Comment: i solved by declairing variable $db inside my Module (class BooksImportedModule extends CWebModule)